# Distribution for which one-sample t-test yields inflated type 1 error rates

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, t-test, type-i-and-ii-errors

Type 1 error rates of the one-sample t-test (two-tailed) can be inflated for example for data from the exponential distribution.

However, I am looking for distributions which yield inflated type 1 error rates but are at the same time symmetric (about their mean).

Comment: Try an equiprobable two-point Bernoulli with a tiny bit of noise added, with small n.

Comment: Thank you. The effect is very small: p(type I error) = 0.0510 and 0.628 for alpha=0.05 and n=5 or 10 samples. Values obtained for a binomial distribution (n=1,p=0.5) + N(0,0.01^2) with 10^6 repetitions.Any idea for a more substantial effect that would also be practically relevant for sample sizes of 10 or larger? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try n=2 3 and 4? With n=2 I would think a 50% type I error rate. But, yeah, with larger sample sizes the convergence is pretty rapid for symmetric distributions. It is worth noting that type II error rates are bad with heavy tailed distributions, but that may not be what you are after.

Comment: Thanks but for n=2,3,4 the distribution is not symmetric anymore or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: The distribution produces the data, right? Sample size is not relevant. It is for the sampling distribution, but I don't think that's what you are talking about. Anyway, the sampling distribution of the mean inherits the symmetry of the parent for all n.

Comment: You were referring to the number of samples; I misunderstood you because in my previous comment n also for the number of repetitions in the binomial distribution

Comment: Oh, Bernoulli is binomial with n=1.

Answer (score 2):

In general, to inflate the type I error you will want a light tailed distribution.  The estimated standard deviation for these tend to underestimate the true standard deviation enough to inflate the type I error in t-tests (heavy tailed distributions are more likely to have the standard deviation over estimated).

A Weibull distribution with shape parameter less than 1 gives a light tailed distribution, but these are also very skewed.  I don't know if you will be able to find a symmetric distribution that is light tailed enough to give you a highly inflated type I error.